# discord.py how does hybrid commands work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem with my discord.py code for my bot. It is not showing up as a slash command in Discord's chat box. I wanted to rewrite my bot that I have been running for many months with discord.py 1.7.3, so I wanted to introduce slash commands. Now I have the problem that with my code the slash commands are not displayed **BUT** they work with the prefix (!), can anyone help me?

Sideinfos:
Discord.py = 2.1.0
Server = Linux
Discord-Server ID: 1000794475683123362
Its not a cog!

```
import sys
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import json
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import random
from random import randint
import datetime
import traceback
import urllib.request, json
import urllib
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext.commands import clean_content
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
from dislash import InteractionClient, SelectMenu, SelectOption
from PIL import Image,ImageFont,ImageDraw
from easy_pil import Editor, load_image_async, Font


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["!","?",","],intents=discord.Intents.all())
botcolor = 0xffffff

@bot.hybrid_command(name='test',description='TEST')
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(1000794475683123362))
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Test!")


bot.run(MyToken)
```

Ive researched the Internet but i didnt find any good anwsers that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Slash commands have to be registered to Discord. This is done through a process called `syncing`. By calling `tree.sync()`, you can push your changes to Discord to let them know about your commands. If you never sync, Discord has no idea you have slash commands.

The exact same applies for regular slash commands as well, this isn't just for hybrids.

**Important note**: do **NOT** auto-sync (syncing automatically in `on_ready` or `setup_hook`). A lot of people online do this, and it's a really bad idea. You should only have to sync whenever you change/remove a command, so not every time your bot starts.

The ratelimits for this API call are very low and unforgiving, so if you spam this by doing it in `on_ready` (every single time your bot starts - which can be very often in development) then you'll get ratelimited.

Syncing should be done in an **owner-only message command**, so only you can call it. If other people have access to this command, they can ratelimit you so hard you'll never be able to sync again.

Syncing is as easy as calling `await bot.tree.sync()` in a message command. If you want to sync to a guild instead of globally, you can pass an ID as an argument.

If you're wondering: the reason that message commands don't have to be synced is because they don't really exist. Discord doesn't know or care about them. These are parsed in your bot itself when the `on_message` event is triggered. Slash commands are integrated into the Discord UI, so this can't be done without pushing it somewhere.

Comment: So i just need to add await.bot.tree.sync() to my message to sync the / for all Servers?
I think i failed.
```@bot.command(name= 'reload')
async def reload(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Reload...")
    await bot.tree.sync() 
    await ctx.send("Tree.sync reloaded")```

Could you check my Code please?

Comment: Code in comments is pretty unreadable, in the future just edit your question. That looks fine, global syncs can take up to an hour to appear so no need to worry just yet. `sync()` returns the commands that it synced, so you can use that output to check if it was successful (eg. by printing it or sending it in Discord). If you want to sync to a guild (which is near-instant instead of global), first run `copy_global_to` and then pass the guild's ID to `sync`. This copies the global commands to that guild and then syncs that guild to Discord.